# Как проверить есть ли введенный номер в базе данных MySQL при нажатии и показать некоторые данные оттуда

Tags: php, mysql

Моя задача, при нажатии на кнопку поиска, проверить есть ли данный номер студента в базе данных и если есть то показать имя и фамилию данного студента ниже. Если данного номера нету то показать соответствуюшее сообшение.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пробовал ето сделать используя форму так как незнаю как проверить нажата ли была кнопка поиска, поетому пробовал `if(isset($_GET['submit']))`, но форма мне ненужна, мне нужно лишь сперва проверить если кнопка поиска была нажата и если да то выполнить действия которые я описывал выше. Сейчас при нажатии ничего не проишодит. Подскажите пожалуйста как ето исправить. 
Вот мой код:

```
<?php include('mysql_connect.php')?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bree+Serif&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/29f1e2c7c5.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Home page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="bg">
    <img src="tech.png" alt="">
</div>

<div id="welcome">
    <div id="inner-wrap">
        <h1>Student management system</h1>
        <h4>Keep control of every student with the options below:</h4>
        <form action="student_management_system.php" method="get">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row no-gutters mt-3 align-items-center">
                <div class="col search-bar">
                    <input class="form-control rounded-pill pr-5" type="search" name="search_student" placeholder="Search by student number" id="example-search-input2">
                </div>
                <div class="col-auto">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn search-btn text-dark border-0 rounded-pill ml-n5">
                        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <?php
                if(isset($_GET['submit'])) {
                    $search = $_GET['search_student'];
                    $trimmedSearch = trim($search);
                    $query = "SELECT * FROM student WHERE student_no = $trimmedSearch";
                    $result = mysqli_query($db_connection, $query);
                    if ($row = mysqli_num_rows($result)) {
                        ?>
                        <div class="alert alert-success">Student found:<?php echo $row['first_name'] . ' ' . $row['last_name'] ?></div>
                        <?php
                    } else {?>
                        <div class="alert alert-danger">Student doesn't exist!</div>
                        <?php
                    }
                }?>
            </div>
        </div>
        </form>
        <div id="main-buttons">
            <button type="button" class="btn main-btns"><a href="add_student.php">Add Student</a></button>
            <button type="button" class="btn main-btns">Update Student</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn main-btns">Delete Student</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: вставьте `var_dump($_GET);` перед `if(isset($_GET['submit']))` и смотрите что у вас приходи после нажатия на кнопку

Comment: `array(1) { ["search_student"]=> string(0) "" }` показывает после нажатия

Answer (score 0):

Правильнее будет сделать на jQuery проверку нажатия на кнопку, а затем, при помощи $.get или $.post, отправлять данные на php обработчик, где и будет проверка всех данных.
Пример отправки полученных данных:

```js
//Ожидание загрузки всей страницы
$(document).ready(function () {
  
  //Проверка клика
  $("#search_input").click(function (e) {
    //Запрещает перезагрузку страницы и отправку формы
    e.preventDefault();
    if(!e.isDefaultPrevented()){
      e.returnValue = false;
    }
    
    //Получение номера, введённого в поле
    let GetNumber = $('#search_input').val();
    
    $.post("you.php", {GetNumber}).done(function (data) {
      alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
    });
    
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="search" name="search_student" placeholder="Search by student number" id="search_input">
<button>Поиск</button>
```

Теперь, когда эти данные приходят на php, получай их там при помощи $_POST['GetNumber'], а дальше крути-верти, как хочешь. (Для вывода результатов поиска просто пиши в php файле echo "Твой контент";

Для проверки наличия данного номера в базе делай следующее:

```
//Получаем список всех пользователей. $_POST['GetNumber'] получаем из примера выше
$CheckUserNum = mysqli_query($bdConnect, ("SELECT * FROM `students` WHERE user_num = '$_POST[GetNumber]'"));
//Преобразовываем ответ в массив
$CheckUserNumRow = mysqli_fetch_array($CheckUserNum);
//Вывод данных
do {
//Тут вид вывода: echo "<div>Content</div";
} while($CheckUserNumRow = mysqli_fetch_array($CheckUserNum));
```